# Get the width and height of an frame image bypassing all the center transparency

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I have many images that contains only frames (styled borders) in PNG format.
All the center of the images are transparent.
I am looking for a way to detect the frame height and width without the transparency.
I tried some pixel by pixel in GDI+ C# to check but didn't manage to make it work correctly.

All this assuming that the top frame height and bottom frame height have the same height and the right frame width and left frame width have the same width.

the frames are linear and shouldn't have any special glitches, so if i detect the width of the right frame i should be the same of the left frame.

Hope anyone have any idea of how to achieve this.

**Frame Example:**

[Frame example http://www.digitalimageautorotate.com/images/frame_demo.png](http://www.digitalimageautorotate.com/images/frame_demo.png)

Comment: Could you show us the code you tried?

Comment: I am sorry, but the code really look ugly and i removed it since it didn't work at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you work with images, you use .LockBits and pointers for speed, since you're typically accessing millions of pixels over and over again. (And if you're not doing it like that - you're probably neglecting  it because you're not realizing how much overhead you get otherwise).

In **this** case however, you will access very few pixels, so .GetPixel should actually be perfectly in order.

```
public Size GetBorderSize(Bitmap bmp)
{
    var hx = bmp.Width/2;
    var hy = bmp.Height/2;
    var sz = new Size();
    while ( bmp.GetPixel(sz.Width, hy).A == 255 && sz.Width < hx)
        sz.Width++;
    while (bmp.GetPixel(hx, sz.Height).A == 255 && sz.Height < hy)
        sz.Height++;
    return sz;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i will try this and let you know.